# Variable inside object wont change publicly

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

This is probably a really dumb question, I hardly know anything about javascript. When I change a variable of an object inside inside one of the class functions it wont change. "I really can't explain things well.." In this case when I try to "Turn Off" this class, this.Status only = Off in the scope of the Stop function.

Note: I'm using Node.js

Code

```
module.exports = class Sniper {

    constructor() {
        this.Status = 'Off'
    }

    async start() {
        this.Status = 'On'

        while (this.Status == 'On') {
            console.log(this.Status)
        }

    }

    stop() {
        //When I try to change this value, it only changes in this scope, so the while loop in the start function keeps running
        this.Status = 'Off'
        console.log(this.Status)
    }

}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded and non-preemptive. While you're in the `while` loop, nothing else can run, so it's not possible to call `stop()`.

Comment: Why is `start()` declared `async`? It never calls any asynchronous functions. Did you think that would make it run in the background, so that you could call `stop` while it's running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created an infinite loop. If you mark a function as `async` it will be still synchronous, but you can start and await `Promises` in it.

This logic won't work, not really sure what do you want exactly, but you cannot stop a synchronous infinite while loop from outside of its scope.

The closest what I can imagine is something like this:

```
 class Sniper {

    constructor() {
        this.Status = 'Off'
    }

    async start() {
        this.Status = 'On'

        while (this.Status === 'On') {
// Lets just give a bit of time for the engine to run other code
            await new Promise(resolve=>setTimeout(resolve,10));
            console.log(this.Status)
        }

    }

    stop() {
        //When I try to change this value, it only changes in this scope, so the while loop in the start function keeps running
        this.Status = 'Off'
        console.log(this.Status)
    }

}

const sniper = new Sniper();

sniper.start();

setTimeout(()=>{
 sniper.stop();
},1000);
```

This will start your loop and you can stop it whenever you want. But as I said, I am not sure what do you want to achieve

Comment: I forgot to remove async, there's more to the code than just that. That's an abstracted version of the actual code. This is what I want to achieve, Imagine a motor that starts when you want it to and stops when u want it to, simple as that.

Comment: Just as others also said, while loop is synchronous, javascript won't run anything else until the current block is not finished. You can 'trick' this like I posted above if you keep it async, if you want that. But your example is still not clear tbh, what do you want to do within the while loop? You _must_ set your end condition from within the loop if you keep it purely sync.

Comment: Inside the while loop I'm going to be making an http request, therefore its async. My goal is to keep sending async requests unless (this.Status == 'Off').

Comment: Then what I said can work, simply `await fetch('https://somewhere.to.post')`, you don't even  have to add a timeout, but beware because you may end up floodiing your endpoint.

Comment: The answer with `setInterval` can work as well, but you need to handle requests longer than the interval, it will not wait async callback to finish, it will simply schedules the next run after x ms.

Comment: Oops, It was working fine, I just a stupid mistake. I had 
setTimeout(sniper.stop, 5000) 
instead of 
setTimeout(()=>{
 sniper.stop();
},1000);
I don't know why It does that though.

Answer (score 0):

If I can understand, you are looking for [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) here. You can start and stop that using intervalId. Better than using while loop and blocking the only execution thread.

```
class Sniper {
  constructor() {
    this.Status = "Off";
    this.intervalId = null;
  }

  start() {
    this.Status = "On";

    this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      console.log(this.Status);
    }, 1000);
  }

  stop() {
    console.log("Turning off!");
    this.Status = "Off";
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
  }
}

const foo = new Sniper();
foo.start();

setTimeout(() => {
  foo.stop();
}, 5000);
```

This will output:

```
On
On
On
On
Turning off!
```

[image: Tried in console]

Comment: There's a problem, I need it to be async.

Comment: Do you want it to be executed at intervals and async both? You can modify the start function as you need.

Comment: Also It doesn't stop, I get.

On
On
On
On
Turning off!
On
On
On
On
On
On
On
On
On
On
On
On
On
...